# Leer imágenes desde Google Drive para un sitio web

Tags: javascript, html5, google-drive

estoy montando una tienda online con base datos en un VPS, y me gustaría saber si puedo guardar las imágenes en una cuenta de Drive, para después cargarlas en la página web.

He leído la documentación sobre la API Rest de Drive, referente a cómo hacerlo desde el navegador mediante javascript, que aunque no es recomendable por la exposición de la clave de API, no importa pues en esa cuenta de Drive sólo habrán imágenes públicas con acceso de sólo lectura. El problema es que según he entendido se requiere de OAuth2 y entonces pide autorizaciones, y es lo que no quiero. También he visto que se pueden usar scripts pero no sé si es la solución adecuada para mi caso.

Otra duda referente a esto sería, cómo haría referencia a estas imágenes, es decir, podría llamarlas después con el nombre de archivo con el que las guardo, o necesito el ID que me proporciona Drive para compartir ¿? porque para mi lo ideal sería por el nombre de archivo.

Estoy un poco perdido con este tema y ando buscando soluciones para ahorrar con la transferencia de datos del sitio web que me cobran en el VPS, y Drive no. No he encontrado muchos ejemplos de código en la red sobre el tema.

Saludos y buena programación.

Comment: Después de tomarme un tiempo y reflexionar sobre el tema, coincido con Cardeol de que es la manera más correcta de implementar un microservicio en el server, en mi caso con Python, que devuelva y pase una lista de las IDs de las imágenes al navegador, para representarlas mediante javascript.

Comment: import pprint
    import sys
    from apiclient.discovery import build

    api_key = 'XxxxxxxxX'
    service = build('drive', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)
    request = service.files().list(pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, 
        name)") 
    response = request.execute()
    pprint.pprint(response)
    if not items:
        print('No se encontraron archivos.')
    else:
        print('Archivos:')
        for item in items:
        print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

Error: "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."

Comment: No entiendo cómo se puede añadir código en los comentarios, le he dejado 4 espacios y nada. Bueno, este es el código del microservicio, estoy usando una clave API simple, ya que quiero un proceso automático, pero como se ve me lanza un error por falta de permisos. La clave API está sin restricciones de aplicación ni de API.

Comment: para poner código en los comentarios se una el símbolo ` o la etiqueta `code` en el menú tienes un botón marcado con **?** donde puedes leer acerca del MD (MarkDown) y etiquetas HTML entre otras muchas cosas interesantes

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtener los ID de imagen utilizando el Servicio [Google Drive Rest API Files List](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list). Luego de ejecutar la consulta puedes referenciar cada imagen con este formato. El URL es abierto y no necesitas exponer la clave del API publicamente.

```
<img src ="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=**TUIDAQUI**&export=download">
```

Ejemplo (con ID 1Lv8poQhQdoGpXLSaSqW6X88CIpX3b29d)

[image]

Comment: El problema de la documentación de Drive es que la mayoría de los ejemplos están hechos para la línea de comandos o el shell, y yo necesito hacerlo en javascript desde el navegador para incluir la lógica de la aplicación, y además sin que OAuth tenga que pedir permisos a nadie, es algo muy básico y llevo días intentando averiguar esto tan sencillo. El único ejemplo que he encontrado es este:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js
pero desconozco si lo puedo usar quitando lo que no necesito, o se requiere de otros métodos. ¿Otro sitio donde me pueda documentar?

Comment: Oauth implica utilizar autenticacion por web para el usuario que esta viendo la aplicacion. La solucion es tener un microservicio json que haga las llamadas te envie los ID de las imagenes. Lo puedes montar en cualquier lado en php java o cualquier backend.

Comment: Pero la idea principal es montar el chiringuito en el frontend con javascript. Las imágenes se deben cargar desde el navegador del cliente y no desde el servidor, se trata de ahorrar ancho de banda en el VPS.

Comment: Pues si, con un microservicio o script solo necesitas javascript del lado del cliente.

Comment: Y ese microservicio o script va dentro del navegador en la página web o el cliente tendría que instalar o descargar algo ¿?
Estuve mirando un poco lo de los microservicios y me pareció un poco lío, no lo tengo muy claro, cómo es ¿? que se necesita para montar uno ¿?

Comment: Basta con un script en php/java/asp.net en cualquier servidor en internet que te muestre un JSON con las imagenes, luego lo llamas utilizando ajax.

Answer (score -1):

Por si alguien llega acá más tarde. Hay una manera más simple de hostear tus imágenes desde Google Drive para tu sitio.

1. Subimos la foto que estamos buscando cargar en nuestra página web. Y le damos a “compartir” apretando click derecho.
2. Tenemos que hacer accesible para las personas alrededor del mundo que busquen acceder a nuestra web. Ahí copiamos el vínculo.
3. Hay que extraer el ID de nuestra imagen y recrear el URL. En [esta pagina](https://clasicwebtools.com/articulos/programacion/host-fotos-GDrive.html) tenes un conversor de urls.